# Keychain persistent data iOS

Tags: ios, keychain

I'm using keychain to save a persistent data.
2 of the functions are

```
func savePassword(password: String, inKeychainItem: NSData?) -> NSData?
func getPasswordWithPersistentReference(persistentReference: NSData) -> String?
```

I just want to make sure, If I use the savePassword function and get a NSData, where should I keep this NSData to keep it persistent to the next time I'll run the app? Is the userDefault is a safe place to keep this data?

Edit: Those are the functions I'm using

```
func savePassword(password: String, inKeychainItem: NSData?) -> NSData? {
        guard let passwordData = password.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false) else { return nil }
        var status = errSecSuccess

        if let persistentReference = inKeychainItem {
            // A persistent reference was given, update the corresponding keychain item.
            let query: [NSObject: AnyObject] = [
                kSecValuePersistentRef : persistentReference,
                kSecReturnAttributes : kCFBooleanTrue
            ]
            var result: AnyObject?

            // Get the current attributes for the item.
            status = SecItemCopyMatching(query, &result)

            if let attributes = result as? [NSObject: AnyObject] where status == errSecSuccess {
                // Update the attributes with the new data.
                var updateQuery = [NSObject: AnyObject]()
                updateQuery[kSecClass] = kSecClassGenericPassword
                updateQuery[kSecAttrService] = attributes[kSecAttrService]

                var newAttributes = attributes
                newAttributes[kSecValueData] = passwordData

                status = SecItemUpdate(updateQuery, newAttributes)
                if status == errSecSuccess {
                    return persistentReference
                }
            }
        }

func getPasswordWithPersistentReference(persistentReference: NSData) -> String? {
        var result: String?
        let query: [NSObject: AnyObject] = [
            kSecClass : kSecClassGenericPassword,
            kSecReturnData : kCFBooleanTrue,
            kSecValuePersistentRef : persistentReference
        ]

        var returnValue: AnyObject?
        let status = SecItemCopyMatching(query, &returnValue)

        if let passwordData = returnValue as? NSData where status == errSecSuccess {
            result = NSString(data: passwordData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as? String
        }
        return result
    }
```

Edit2: basically, I just want to check if I saved a password and if I did then I want to get it. For this I need a persistentReference. I'm getting one from the save password function. but where should I keep it?

Comment: Those functions are not part of the iOS SDK. You'll have to edit your question to include the source code for them if you want help using them.

Comment: I thought the return type of those functions should be enough, but will edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use function to store password in secure. It's safe enough to write your key data in plaintext way. Because no one can access your keychain.

[In iOS, each application always has access to its own keychain items; the user is never asked to unlock the keychain.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH204-TP9)

that no way to access content info of your keychain.